# Probability involving chess board

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

if 2 cells are chosen at random on a chess board what is the probability that they will have a common side
i tried solving the question by considering different cases for the cells on:
1. corner
2. edge other than corner
3. cell in middle

but i guess the cases might be repeating 
so please help

Comment: What's a common side???

Comment: the cells being adjacent

Comment: Have you learned conditional probability?

Comment: yes i know the basics including bayes

Comment: yes proceed the way you are doing and divide the number of cases by 2 as you are counting each case twice

Comment: ok thnx will try again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $64$ cells:

- $36$ cells have $4$ neighbors each
- $24$ cells have $3$ neighbors each
- $ 4$ cells have $2$ neighbors each

The total number of ways to choose $2$ out of $64$ cells is $\binom{64}{2}=2016$.

The number of ways to choose $2$ adjacent cells is $\frac{36\cdot4+24\cdot3+4\cdot2}{2!}=112$.

So the probability of choosing $2$ adjacent cells is $\frac{112}{2016}=\frac{1}{18}$.

Comment: can you explain the no. of neighbours

Comment: @SukrutNigwekar: Each middle square has $4$ of its sides common with others. Each side square has $3$ of its sides common with others. Each corner square has $2$ of its sides common with others.

Comment: yes got it now thnx

Answer (score 4):

Another way to count adjacent cells is to count internal edges (borders between two cells).  For each internal edge, there is a pair of adjacent cells.  Horizontally there are $7$ lines of internal edges, each with $8$ internal edges; for a total of $56$ horizontal internal edges.  Likewise there are $56$ vertical internal edges.  Thus there are $112$ internal edges, and consequently there are $112$ pairs of adjacent squares.

So the probability of two randomly chosen squares being adjacent is $\frac{112}{64\choose 2}$

Same as Barak Manos' nice answer; but a different approach.

Comment: wow great method