# Two squares are chosen on a chessboard at random - Probability

Tags: probability

> Two squares are chosen on a chessboard at random. What is the
> probability that they have a side in common?

There are many explanations available in internet for this question and it is clear that answer is $\dfrac{1}{18}$. This is an easy question and I am very clear.

But, It seems the answer $\dfrac{1}{18}$ assumes that only 64 squares are there in chess board which is fine because the question may be considered in that way.

But what happens when we consider all the 204 squares of the chess board?

Most of the answers I saw did not consider this and I tried doing it myself. On further search, I found two answers  which I present it here to be clear.

> When we consider all the 204 squares,
>
> [lofoya.com](http://www.lofoya.com/aptitude/probability/two-squares-are-chosen-at-random-on-a-chessboard-what-is-the-probability-that-they.php) gives answer as
> $\dfrac{222}{204C2}$
>
> [careerbless.com](http://www.careerbless.com/qna/discuss.php?questionid=2439#top) gives answer as $\dfrac{228}{204C2}$

I tried doing it with the help of a figure with small examples and see $\dfrac{228}{204C2}$ can be the right answer. Can anyone help in this regard?

Comment: Which 204 squares? - Ah I see from the link. At least the computations on lofoya.com are obviously wrong (there are 10 cases for $4\times 4$ squares)

Comment: total squares is 204 including 1*1 , 2*2, ... 8*8, right?

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1129062/131263).

Comment: @barak manos, not duplicate. The question you have mentioned is focusing on the first case where 1/18 is the answer. Here, the question is focusing on all squares and hence going in a different angle

Comment: @Kiran: I was referring to the question at the top of your post (emphasized in pink background on my browser). Perhaps you should change that question, because as stated, it's pretty much duplicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On an $n\times n$ chessboard, there are $(n+1-k)^2$ squares of size $k\times k$ that we have to count. So the number of total cases is 
$$\tag1 {1^2+2^2+\ldots + n^2\choose 2}={\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\choose 2}.$$
To have two horizontally adjacent $k\times k$ squares, there are $n+1-k$ choices for the vertical position and $n+1-2k$ choices for the horizontal position. As we have to consider the vertical case as well, we arrive at 
$$ 2\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\rfloor}(n+1-k)(n+1-2k)$$
where the sum stops at $m:=\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\rfloor$ because only $k$ with $n+1-2k\ge 0$ make sense. Transforming we get
$$\tag2\begin{align}2\sum_{k=1}^m(n+1-k)(n+1-2k)&=
2\sum_{k=1}^m(n+1)^2-6(n+1)\sum_{k=1}^mk+4\sum_{k=1}^mk^2\\
&=2m(n+1)^2-3(n+1)m(m+1)+\frac23{m(m+1)(2m+1)}\\
\end{align} $$
favorable cases and a probability of $(2)/(1)$.
For $n=8$ (and $m=4$) this is
$$p_8=\frac{228}{204\choose 2}=\frac{38}{3451} $$
and for $n\gg 0$ we have
$$p_n\approx \frac{15}{2n^3} $$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the problem on an $n\times n$ chessboard, and count the number of adjacent cells. There are $n(n-1)$ vertical pairs, which we see by first choosing one of $n$ columns and then choosing the topmost cell of a pair in $n-1$ ways. By symmetry there are $n(n-1)$ horizontal pairs, so the probability is
$$
\frac{2n(n-1)}{\binom{n^2}{2}} = \frac{2n(n-1)}{\frac{n^2(n^2 - 1)}{2}} = \frac{4}{n(n+1)}.
$$

Comment: in 8*8 chessboard, the answer is then 4/(8*9) = 1/18 which is ok. But, what if we consider the 204 squares as mentioned here http://www.careerbless.com/qna/discuss.php?questionid=1310

Answer (score 1):

The $\frac {228}{^{204}C_2}$ is correct.  They disagree on the number of pairs of $4 \times 4$ squares that share a border.  If the squares are above each other, there are five choices for the leftmost column.  Similarly if the squares are side by side you can choose the top border in $5$ ways, so there are $10$ pairs of $4 \times 4$ squares that share a border, which is part of the $228$ calculation.  The $222$ calculation only seems to have included the four pairs you get by taking quadrants of the board as the $4 \times 4$ squares.